# Disable Sounds with a Profile

Tags: ios, iphone, app-config, audio, profiles

I want to disable sounds like Keyboard Clicks and configure the other sounds, is it Possible to create a Profile which can handle this.
I tried the iPhone Configuration Utility, also the Apple Configurator, but i didnt find options for that.
so my questions is, is it possible and need i a special program?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible It may be possible using private frameworks, but your app would not be approved for sale on the iTunes App Store if you used them.

Comment: I dont want to create an App, i want to configure my iPhone for the first set up.